# Proof is wrong, but I don't understand why.

Tags: real-analysis

I recently got this question wrong on a homework and after looking at my professors explanation I'm still failing to understand what's wrong with my proof. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Suppose that the function
$$f: [ 0, 1]  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

is continuous and that
$$f( x) \geq 0,\; \forall x \in [ 0, 1]$$
Prove that
$$\int ^{1}_{0}  f >0$$
if and only if there is a point $x_{0} \in [ 0, 1]$  at which $f( x_{0})   > 0.$*

\begin{array}{l}
Proof\ by\ contradictin:Suppose\ that\ the\ function\ f:\ [ 0,\ 1] \ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} .\ is\ continuous\ and\ that\ \\
f( x) \geq 0\ \ for\ all\ x\ in\ [ 0,\ 1] .\ prove\ that\ \int ^{1}_{0} \ f >0\ iff\ \forall x_{0} \ in\ [ 0,\ 1] \ f( x_{0}) \leq 0\\
\\
\forall x_{0} \ in\ [ 0,\ 1] \ f( x_{0}) \leq 0\ \Longrightarrow \ \int ^{1}_{0} \ f >0\\
We\ know\ that\ the\ function\ is\ always\ greater\ than\ or\ equal\ to\ zero,\ so\ for\ f( x_{0}) \ to\ be\ less\ than\ \\
or\ equal\ to\ 0,\ \forall x_{0} \ in\ [ 0,\ 1] \ \ f( x) \ must\ be\ 0\ on\ [ 0,1] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ( 0\leq f( x_{0}) \leq 0)\\
\\
this\ means\ f\ is\ a\ constant\ ( c=0) \ on\ [ 0,1] .\\
\\
\int ^{1}_{0} \ f=0( b-a) =0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ( example\ 6.5)\\
\\
This\ contradicts\ the\ above\ statement.\ \\
\\
\\
\int ^{1}_{0} \ f >0\ \Longrightarrow \forall x_{0} \ in\ [ 0,\ 1] \ f( x_{0}) \leq 0\\
\\
0< \int ^{1}_{0} \ f\leq U( f,\ P) =\sum ^{n}_{i=1} M_{i}( x_{i} -x_{i-1}) .\\
\\
0< \sum ^{n}_{i=1} M_{i}( x_{i} -x_{i-1}) \ \\
\therefore \ becuase\ ( x_{i} -x_{i-1}) \ is\ positive\ there\ must\ exist\ some\ M_{i}  >0\ \ \ \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ( the\ sum\ of\ all\ negative\ or\ zero\ numbers\ is\ \leq 0)\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
\therefore \ \exists x_{0} \ in\ [ 0,\ 1] \ s.t.f( x_{0}) \  >\ 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [ M_{i} \ =\ sup\{f( x) \ |\ x\ in\ [ x_{i-1} ,\ x_{i}]\}]\\
\\
This\ contradicts\ the\ above\ statement.
\end{array}

Comment: There are two directions. One, the integral being positive implies the existence of a point with the stated property, and the other, the existence of a point with the stated property implies the positivity of the integral. Ideally your solution would make both directions express and explicit (even if there is some thematic overlap between the arguments). Your argument does not appear to explicitly draw upon the assumed continuity of $f$, which is definitely a part of it. Where do you use that $f$ is continuous? Do you see how the result can fail if $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The formatting is pretty wacky... here's a [reference and tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for fixing it.

Comment: You correctly proved (by proving the contrapositive) that if $\int_0^1f(x) ~ dx \gt 0$, then there is some point $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ with $f(x_0) \gt 0$.  I can't follow your attempt to prove the other direction because I don't know what you mean by $U, P, M_i,$ and $x_i$.  Edit your question to define those explicitly and you may see the problem yourself.  If not, I'm sure someone here will be willing to guide you.

Comment: On the topic of continuity being necessary and any attempt at a proof who doesn't utilize the fact that $f$ is continuous must be wrong, consider as an example $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=0.5\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ whose integral is zero despite having an $x$ value such that $f(x)>0$

Comment: @Théophile ... I doubt the OP formatted this himself in LaTeX.  It looks more like it was formatted in some other system (perhaps Word), then automatically "converted" to LaTeX.

Comment: i reformatted a paragraph of your post- this can guide you to format the remaining text.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an if and only if (iff) statement, you must prove it both ways.

If $\int_0^1 f(x) > 0$ then there is an $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_{0})>0$

This direction you can prove with proof by contradiction:

Suppose $g(x) = 0$ and $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx > 0$

If $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b],$ with $f(x), g(x)$ integrable and $a<b,$  then $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx \leq \int_a^b g(x)\ dx$

$\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx \le \int_0^1 g(x)\ dx = 0$

Contradiction

However, you still must prove the other direction.

If there is an $x_{0}\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_{0})>0,$ and $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 f(x) > 0$

Since $f$ is continuous, there must be some neighborhood around $x_0$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in this neighborhood.

This creates a sub-interval where the integral is strictly positive.

For the remaining sub-intervals

$f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ implies the integral is greater than or equal to zero for all sub intervals.

This makes the integral strictly positive.